# Bootstrap Datetimepicker displays "Undefined" in pop-up window

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am building a compenent which uses the [bootstrap dataetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options) created by Eonasdan.

I am havinga problem when setting the pickTime property and after banging my head against my desk was wondering if anyone has seen anything similar and can help point me in the right direction?

My mark-up for the datetimepicker is:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="entryDatePicker">
    <input type="text" id="txtEntryDate" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

The script for the datetimepicker is:

```
$('#entryDatePicker').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    pickDate: true,
    icons: {
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
    }
});
```

If I don't have the property pickTime it works fine and I can see the pop-up calendar and everything appears to be ticketyboo but when I add this property I just see "undefined" in the pop-up and the generated source looks like:

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu bottom" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 802.65625px; left: 621.78125px; right: auto;">
    <div class="datepicker">undefined</div>
</div>
```

I have checked the console and there are no script errors being generated so I'm kind of at a loss to what would be causing this strange behaviour.  I have used this control several times before and this is the first time this has happened.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by a previous bootstrap that was already implemented in the solution.  I downgraded the datetimepicker to a suitable version and hey presto!

Credit goes to a team member!